# sed script clobbering one of the files

Tags: unix, sed

I am having trouble trying to get this script to work correctly. Specifically in one spot. Script is as follows:

```
egrep -v "total" asg4edb > /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/t1
egrep ":" t1 > /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/t2
sed 's/^-/r/' t2 > t1
sed 's/cm325d06/me/' t1 > t2
sed 's/cm325d/gang/' t2 > t1
sed 's/^d/A/' t1 > t2
sed 's/^\./Z/' t2 > t1
egrep '^Z' t1 > subdirs
egrep '^r|^A' t1 > /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/files4
sed 's/rwx/7/;s/rw-/6/;s/r-x/5/;s/r--/4/;s/-wx/3/;s/-w-/2/;s/--x/1/;s/---/0/' /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/files4 > /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/files4
echo -e "cm325d06 \t Gilman \t Randy" > /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/asg4edf
( echo " " ; echo " " ) >> /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/asg4edf
cat /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/subdirs >> /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/asg4edf
( echo " " ; echo " " ) >> /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/asg4edf
cat /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/files4 >> /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/asg4edf
rm /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/t1 /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/t2 /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/subdirs
```

When I try to open my files4 file it is empty.

This command:

```
sed 's/rwx/7/;s/rw-/6/;s/r-x/5/;s/r--/4/;s/-wx/3/;s/-w-/2/;s/--x/1/;s/---/0/' /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/files4 > /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/files4
```

It doesn't make sense because when I add the ">>" to it it will just add the data to the rest of the file. However, I need it to overwrite the old data. I am really confused of why this is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you post original data and what you like to do with it and what to get out of it, we may help you create a much more simple script.  This looks way over complicated.

Comment: You need to use a variable name for the file, and then repeat that: `file=/class/cm325d/06/dASG4/asg4edf` and use `$file`.  The repetition of long names barely differentiated at the end makes it hard to read your script.

Comment: You need to take a step back and reevaluate which tools you use for which problems. shell is simply an environment from which to call tools. grep is a tool for finding regexps in files and printing the matching lines. sed is a tool for simple substitutions on a single line. If you need to do any more than one OR the other of those things then you should be using awk, the tool for general text manipulation. Get the book Effective Awk Programing by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Core problem

The fundamental problem has been accurately diagnosed by [Wintermute](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4301306/wintermute) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28383898/15168).  The line:

```
sed 's/rwx/7/;s/rw-/6/;s/r-x/5/;s/r--/4/;s/-wx/3/;s/-w-/2/;s/--x/1/;s/---/0/' \
    /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/files4 > /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/files4
```

clobbers the file `/class/cm325d/06/dASG4/files4`.

#### But there's more…

The whole script is screaming for a rewrite.  It appears that the current directory is `/class/cm325d/06/dASG4/` (otherwise, the `t1` referenced in the second line of the script is not the file created in the first line, and the `t2` referenced in the third line is not the one created in the second line).  This allows us to radically simplify the script.

#### Original

```
egrep -v "total" asg4edb > /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/t1
egrep ":" t1 > /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/t2
sed 's/^-/r/' t2 > t1
sed 's/cm325d06/me/' t1 > t2
sed 's/cm325d/gang/' t2 > t1
sed 's/^d/A/' t1 > t2
sed 's/^\./Z/' t2 > t1
egrep '^Z' t1 > subdirs
egrep '^r|^A' t1 > /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/files4
sed 's/rwx/7/;s/rw-/6/;s/r-x/5/;s/r--/4/;s/-wx/3/;s/-w-/2/;s/--x/1/;s/---/0/' /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/files4 > /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/files4
echo -e "cm325d06 \t Gilman \t Randy" > /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/asg4edf
( echo " " ; echo " " ) >> /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/asg4edf
cat /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/subdirs >> /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/asg4edf
( echo " " ; echo " " ) >> /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/asg4edf
cat /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/files4 >> /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/asg4edf
rm /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/t1 /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/t2 /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/subdirs
```

#### Current directory

```
cd /class/cm325d/06/dASG4 || exit 1  # Optional

egrep -v "total" asg4edb > t1
egrep ":" t1 > t2
sed 's/^-/r/' t2 > t1
sed 's/cm325d06/me/' t1 > t2
sed 's/cm325d/gang/' t2 > t1
sed 's/^d/A/' t1 > t2
sed 's/^\./Z/' t2 > t1
egrep '^Z' t1 > subdirs
egrep '^r|^A' t1 > files4
sed 's/rwx/7/;s/rw-/6/;s/r-x/5/;s/r--/4/;s/-wx/3/;s/-w-/2/;s/--x/1/;s/---/0/' \
    files4 > files5    # Bug fix 1
mv files5 files4       # Preserve files4 as output 
echo -e "cm325d06 \t Gilman \t Randy" > asg4edf
( echo " " ; echo " " ) >> asg4edf
cat subdirs >> asg4edf
( echo " " ; echo " " ) >> asg4edf
cat files4 >> asg4edf
rm t1 t2 subdirs
```

I'm left wondering whether `files4` should have been deleted too.  The input was `asg4edb`; the output is `asg4edf` and `files4`.

#### Combining commands

Now we can look at various groups of commands.  The initial `egrep` and `sed` commands can be done in a single operation using just `sed`:

```
sed -e '/total/d' \
    -e '/:/!d' \
    -e 's/^-/r/' \
    -e 's/cm325d06/me/' \
    -e 's/cm325d/gang/' \
    -e 's/^d/A/' \
    -e 's/^\./Z/' \
    asg4edb > t1
```

Each of the `-e` options corresponds to a complete command, kept in sequence.  In fact, even the next two `egrep` operations, which write information to `subdirs` and `files4`, can be managed in the same `sed` script:

```
sed -e '/total/d' \
    -e '/:/!d' \
    -e 's/^-/r/' \
    -e 's/cm325d06/me/' \
    -e 's/cm325d/gang/' \
    -e 's/^d/A/' \
    -e 's/^\./Z/' \
    -e '/^Z/w subdirs \
    -e '/^[rA]/w files4 \
    -n asg4edb
```

The `-n` option reflects the fact that we no longer need the standard output.

#### And the permissions mapping too

Indeed, we can also do the permissions mapping `sed` operation in this single `sed` script.  The permissions mapping only applies to regular files (`r`) or directories (`A`), not to other file types (`Z`).  It also does peculiar things like:

```
rwxr-x--x     -->  751      # Perfectly OK
r-xr-x--x     -->  5r-x1    # Really?
rw-r--r--     -->  64r--    # Really?
r--r--r--     -->  4r--r--  # Really?
```

There should be a `g` modifier on each substitution.

```
sed -e '/total/d' \
    -e '/:/!d' \
    -e 's/^-/r/' \
    -e 's/cm325d06/me/' \
    -e 's/cm325d/gang/' \
    -e 's/^d/A/' \
    -e 's/^\./Z/' \
    -e '/^[rA]/{
           s/rwx/7/g
           s/rw-/6/g
           s/r-x/5/g
           s/r--/4/g
           s/-wx/3/g
           s/-w-/2/g
           s/--x/1/g
           s/---/0/g
           w files4
       }' \
    -e '/^Z/w subdirs \
    -n asg4edb
```

The conditional block emphasizes that the permissions mapping doesn't happen for the lines prefixed with `Z` in the original script.

#### Reassembly

The final steps reassemble `files4` and sundry other data into the output file, `asg4edf`.  We can do that with a single redirection operation:

```
{
echo -e "cm325d06 \t Gilman \t Randy"
echo " "
echo " "
cat subdirs
echo " "
echo " "
cat /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/files4
} > asg4edf
```

I'm a little sceptical about the blanks around the tabs, and the lines containing a single blank.  I suspect you'd do better with:

```
{
printf "cm325d06\tGilman\tRandy\n\n"
cat subdirs
printf "\n\n"
cat /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/files4
} > asg4edf
```

#### Final version

```
cd /class/cm325d/06/dASG4 || exit 1  # Optional

sed -e '/total/d' \
    -e '/:/!d' \
    -e 's/^-/r/' \
    -e 's/cm325d06/me/' \
    -e 's/cm325d/gang/' \
    -e 's/^d/A/' \
    -e 's/^\./Z/' \
    -e '/^[rA]/{
           s/rwx/7/g
           s/rw-/6/g
           s/r-x/5/g
           s/r--/4/g
           s/-wx/3/g
           s/-w-/2/g
           s/--x/1/g
           s/---/0/g
           w files4
       }' \
    -e '/^Z/w subdirs \
    -n asg4edb
{
printf "cm325d06\tGilman\tRandy\n\n"
cat subdirs
printf "\n\n"
cat /class/cm325d/06/dASG4/files4
} > asg4edf
rm subdirs  # files4 too?
```

#### No — it isn't perfect yet

Note that there are still improvements that could (and arguably should) be made.  For example:

- The script could have trap interrupts etc and remove intermediate files before exiting, so it leaves things in the state it found them.
- It could ignore interrupts while generating the final output file, too.  That's probably OTT for this exercise, though.
- The intermediate file names (`subdirs` and `files4`) could be generated with the `mktemp` command too.
- The script could take the input and output file names as arguments.

Comment: Wow this is very good and makes it look cleaner thank you a lot for the examples. I am sorry that my code looks so bad I am my 4th week of intro to UNIX so I am still learning.

Comment: Additionally, thanks for the g option on the substitution that fixed the other problem I was having. You really know what you are doing. Thank you again my script meets all the criteria now.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not sed, it's the way the shell handles redirection. In a command `foo > bar`, the file bar is created/truncated before `foo` is executed. You can see this happen, for example, with

```
# make sure somefile is not an important file!
tac somefile > somefile
```

...which will leave you with an empty file. (I would have used `cat`, but `bash` recognizes that special case and gives a warning). Since your command is essentially

```
sed 'some code' filename > filename
```

this happens to you. If you want to edit files in place with `sed`, use its `-i` option:

```
sed -i 's/foo/bar/;s/baz/qux/' filename
```

Note that BSD sed, which you're likely to have on *BSD or MacOS X, requires `-i` to have an extension parameter, such as

```
sed -i.bak 's/foo/bar/;s/baz/qux/' filename
```

This will place a backup of the original file in `filename.bak`. You can do this with GNU sed (which you're likely to have on Linux) as well, and you can use `-i ''` if you don't want a backup with BSD sed.

Note that editing files in place without a backup is unsafe in that if your machine crashes at the wrong time (for example), you can end up both without the original file and without the result of the transformation. I prefer to use

```
sed -i.bak 's/foo/bar/;s/baz/qux/' filename && rm filename.bak
```

for this reason, which will delete the backup only if `sed` reported success.